# Spatial Join in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, spatial

I come from a mining and exploration background. I have a list of points (with ID and X and Y coordinates).

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7v3C.png)

I have another table which contains polygons (claim numbers).
I am trying to find out which points fall within which polygons. My coordinates are in UTM Projection.

Thank you in advance!

I was trying the following code however my query is not returning results.

```
SELECT 
      pg.claim_number, 
      p.DHId 
FROM leasehold as pg
JOIN
(SELECT 
     DHId, 
     X, 
     Y,
     geometry::STPointFromText('POINT(',X,' ',Y,'), 0) AS [geom]
 FROM collar 
      WHERE X is not null AND 
      Y is not null AND 
      claim_number is null) AS p
ON pg.Shape.STIntersects(p.geom) = 1
```

I was expecting to get a list with claim_number from polygon table which each DHId from point table intersects or falls within.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there just a syntax/quoting issue. I cleaned it up a bit and replaced `STPointFromText` with `Point` which is an MS-specific extension but doesn't require you to create WKT just to get a point. But that's really all I changed - I'd expect your general approach to work.

```sql
SELECT 
      pg.claim_number, 
      p.DHId 
FROM leasehold as pg
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        DHId, 
        X, 
        Y,
        geometry::Point(X, Y, 0) AS [geom]
    FROM collar 
    WHERE X is not null AND 
        Y is not null AND 
        claim_number is null
) AS p
    ON pg.Shape.STIntersects(p.geom) = 1;
```

That said, I would expect this to not be super performant. You're creating the points on the fly and so will be incurring that cost at run time. As such, there's no way to put a spatial index on that data. If you can, I'd suggest adding a column to your collar table that is the geometry point and, as I implied, put a spatial index on it. Also, if there's not an index on the leasehold.Shape column, I'd put one there as well.

Comment: Thank you @BenThul. I am new to Spatial SQL. I just noticed that the two tables mentioned in my Query above are using two different SRIDs. I suppose that could be why I am not getting any results since the feature don't intersect at all due to being in different projections. Is there a way I can convert the geometry of one of these table.

Comment: Since you're creating the Point instances on the fly, you're free to specify whatever SRID you want. The [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/point-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver16) of the `Point()` function is `Point(X, Y, SRID)`, so you should be able to put an appropriate value in for the 0 that you're specifying now. Also, I'd recommend using geography instead of geometry if you can and it's appropriate (i.e. the data represent points/areas on the Earth rather than on a flat plane).

Comment: Unless you're saying that the source data has been captured/reported in differing SRIDs. In which case, you'll have to convert/reproject one of them.

Comment: I think it's more correct to use point.STWithin(polygon). And yes, your SRIDs should match but SQL server doesn't do any reprojections so, if your stuff is "actually" different coordinates, you have to reproject them manually

Comment: @siggemannen - would you care to elaborate on why `STWithin()` is more correct? My reading of the difference is that `a.STWithin(b)` returns true if all of a intersects with b while `a.STIntersects(b)` returns true if any of a intersects with b. In this case, given that a is a point, these two functions should behave identically. But if you know something I don't, I'm happy to learn.

Comment: @ben, You know, it's a very good question! "correct" was the wrong word. It just feels more natural to me to use STWithin when reasoning about points inside polygons, and STintersects is more about Lines crossing or overlapping polygons. Also, my natural reaction was that testing for STWithin of a point is a faster operation than STInterects, but it's also more of a feeling that truth.